# Using chipKIT WiFi Shield with an Arduino

Tags: wifi, shields, chipkit

I'm beginning with Arduino and I have to make two of them communicate via WiFi. I'm going to implement the examples for a WiFi Client and WiFi Server in their [tutorials page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial).

The problem is I only have one Arduino WiFi Shield which is working fine. But I also have a [chipKIT WiFi Shield](http://store.digilentinc.com/chipkit-wifi-shield-add-on-board/).

My question is: Can I use this other shield to do what I want with one of my Arduinos (I have Uno, Mega and Due) and how? Because I've plugged the shield and I've uploaded the code but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. The only libraries available for the chipKIT WiFi Shield are written specifically for the chipKIT boards.

Also, how have you plugged the board into an Arduino? The chipKIT WiFi Shield has Digilent's own header layout with a double row of headers where the Arduino only has a single row. Half the pins won't be plugged into anything.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know much about chipKIT products. Only that I could use Arduino IDE also. And since I could plug it into a Uno I thought they could be compatible. The picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/32pv2t0e0s1ptrh/2017-06-15%2007.19.04.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Look from the end - you'll see half the pins dangling in mid air.

Comment: You want something like an Uno32, uC32 or MAX32 to work with the WiFi Shield.

Comment: You're right, Majenko. But I thought that this was "normal". For some reason I thought the pins were like that so I could plug into different board sizes. My mistake. First time using shields.